# Wordpress keeps automatically inserts <br/>

Tags: shortcode

I'm using the 'SyntaxHighlighter Evolved' plugin on Wordpress and when I create a code block, it keeps inserting a `<br/>`. If I put everything on one line, of course, it would not insert them. I want to be able to have a code block with multiple lines without the `<br/>`.

Here is what I'm typing:
[image]

Here is what the preview displays:
[image]

How do I remove the `<br />` while keeping the new lines?

Comment: If you mean the Shortcode block in Gutenberg, then it's perfectly normal for the `<br />` to be automatically added because the block's render callback applies [`wpautop()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/) on the shortcode (or block content). It's easy to override the block, but why not use the Code block for multi-line shortcodes?

Comment: What do you mean by "Code block for multi-line shortcodes"? How do I do that? (Sorry...I'm new to wordpress)

Comment: Click on the `+` ("Add Block") button and choose the "Code" block, then just put your shortcode into the block content. (And you can use the short version of the shortcode - `[python]code here[/python]`)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the 2nd line (the first code line) just after the shortcode, as in

```
[sourcecode language = python]a+b=c
f = 1 + 3
c = 12 + 13
```

(not actually code, but you see what I did.) You put a blank line after the shortcode, which was interpreted as a

Just guessing here; you might want to ask the plugin support forum.

Comment: The rest of the lines will still have `<br />`